# How should I deal with a circular import in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If I have "a.py"

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class A(db.Model):
    db.ReferenceProperty(b.B)
    ...other stuff
```

and another file "b.py"

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class B(db.Model):
    db.ReferenceProperty(a.A)
    ...other stuff
```

It would appear that Python simply does not allow circular dependencies. Normally I guess you would alter the code such that the two classes actually can resolve themselves without importing one another directly. Perhaps by consolidating their reference to one another through a third intermediary? But I can't just use a normal intermediary class, as all classes would ultimately need to be persisted to the database? Is there any correct solution to structuring the above code such that it works?

I have a feeling that I am going to get a lot of "bad smelling code", "decouple", "bad design", etc comments. So I ask that if you say that, please illustrate what you would do with an actual example. Are there any solutions that would involve leaving the references, classes, and modules as they stand?

Thank you.

Comment: As you say, bad code smell - why do you want to have circular references between classes outside of a common module, aside from natural programmer laze?

Comment: You need this when you want a one to one relationship where two persistent objects are able to refer to one another.

Comment: Well specifically, I have a Question (db.Model entity), that is supposed to have one or more Answers (db.Model entity). Each of these Answers may however point to another Question, used for further clarification, or to a Result (db.Model entity).

Comment: +1 because there are actually situations where these circular references are needed for the best solution.

Comment: This is like working in C, but not being allowed headers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround is to have a ReferenceProperty in at least one of the models that doesn't restrict itself to a particular class, and then enforce only referencing that class in your own code.

e.g.,

```
class A(db.Model):
  b = db.ReferenceProperty()

class B(db.Model):
  a = db.ReferenceProperty(A)
```

You'll be able to assign any model instance to the b variable; just make sure you only assign actual Bs.

Comment: That is what I have done. It is kind of lame, I mean I was hoping to maybe re-open one of the classes and then "inject" a reference attribute after they were both instantiated, but whatever. I suppose this will be the correct answer  unless I see something better.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you define both models in the same module? e.g. a_b.py

Comment: I did give that a try. Same thing though, the problem isn't that they are in separate files (I believe) it is that they reference one another.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#References):

> ReferenceProperty has another handy
>   feature: back-references. When a model
>   has a ReferenceProperty to another
>   model, each referenced entity gets a
>   property whose value is a Query that
>   returns all of the entities of the
>   first model that refer to it.

So you should probably be able to use the automatically added back-reference.

Comment: This is exactly what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to keep A and B in a sort of tree structure, so things can reference one another from the root to leaf direction, but not from the leaf to root direction. Your solution to have the "leaves" refer to the "roots" and then use the auto generated back-reference from the "roots" to the "leaves" might solve the circular dependency, but would intwine the tree.

Comment: A backreference is not the same as a reference in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you can replace the circular dependency with an intersection table.

In my case, I have denormalized models, `Player` and `Match`.

The relationship between Matches and Players is many-to-many, (a Player has played one-or-more matches, and a Match references one-or-more players).

What I needed:

```
class Match(db.Model):
    p1 = db.ReferenceProperty( Player )
    p2 = db.ReferenceProperty( Player )

class Player(db.Model):
    # Remember what match player is currently in, for victor reporting
    currentMatch = db.ReferenceProperty( Match )
```

### Option 0: What [Wooble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912396/111307) suggested

### Option 1: Normalize it (use an intersection table)

```
class Match(db.Model):
    # ...

class Player(db.Model):
    # ...

# Every match has multiple entries here (as many 1 for
# each player-in-match entry).  This will make retrieval
# slower, but more-correct (it is "normalized" now)
class PlayersInMatches(db.Model):
    player=db.ReferenceProperty(Player)
    match=db.ReferenceProperty(Match)
    isCurrent=db.BooleanProperty()
```